# How to style with data conditions from another json in Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: javascript, json, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

So I have two json files, in the first are the geometries for the trains stations while in the second json file is the data of how many passengers got on/off at each station for the past ten years (without a geometry).

The Stations Geometry Features in the first json file which has allready been added as a layer to the map (using Mapbox GL JS)

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "stationen_offset500000",
"features": [
{ 
"type": "Feature", 
"properties": { 
        "np_id": 10312, 
        "station": "Somewhere Main Station",
        "gid": 1123 }, 
        "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ ...] ] ]}};
```

And the Entrants/Dropoff json file with the data:

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "einAussteiger",
"features": [
{ 
"type": "Feature", 
"properties": { 
        "np_id": 10038, 
        "station": "Somewhere Main Station", 
        "avg_entrants_day": "339,344", 
        "avg_dropoff_day": "391,266", 
        "year": 2018, 
        "id": 1 }}
```

My goal is to set the extrusion-height of the stations polygon depending on the avg_entrants_day given a specific year. But I don't really know how to do that since the data is in two different json files.

I have fiddled arround by calling

```
map.setPaintProperty("stations_offset500000", 'fill-extrusion-height', [
  "match",
  ["get", "..."],
])
```

in various versions, but it was no use honestly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is simply:

1. Fetch the first file.
2. Fetch the second file.
3. Loop over features in the first file, adding properties from the second one.
4. Add it to the map.